# How to restrict access to not logged users to certain pages? (JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I am implementing my own authentication mechanism and i want to know if what i am doing is correct and if not how can i do it correctly.

First ill explain how my authentication mechanism works:

-The details of my users are inside an object called Role. This object contains 3 fields:

email:`String`

password:`String`

userType:`Enum`

-When the user accesses the system, the object Role is saved into the session.

My question is: How can i restrict the access to certain pages to users(Role) based in their `userType` fields?

This is what i do but doesnt work.

First i have a managed bean that checks if the usser is logged.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityController {

    //Some attributes...


    public String redirectNotBuyer() {
        Role role = (Role) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("userRole");
        //Checks if user is logged
        if (role == null) {         
            // Please login
            //Add message to authentification
            return "login.xhtml";           
        } else if (role != null) {
            if (!role.getType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("BUYER")) {
                // Buyer not authorized
                return "main.xhtml";
            }
        }       
        return null;
    }

    public String redirectNotSeller() {
        Role role = (Role) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("userRole");
        if (role == null) {
            // Please login
            //Add message to authentification
            return "login.xhtml";           
        } else if (role != null) {
            if (!role.getType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("SELLERs")) {
                // Buyer not authorized
                return "main.xhtml";
            }
        }       
        return null;
    }

//Getters, setters...
```

Those 2 methods above redirect in case the user is not a Buyer and in case the user is not a seller.

So now what i do is in the page that i dont want the user to go i call one of those methods, so the user gets redirected to the main page.
Example: A non authorized user enters a page that is called buyOffer.xhtml, that only BUYERS can access:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">


<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <!-- THE REGISTRATION FORM -->
    <ui:define name="buyOfferForm">
       <h2>Buy offer</h2>
       #{SecurityController.redirectNotBuyer()}
    </ui:define>            
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

For some reason when i go to this page with a not logged in user or a user that is not has BUYER as userType, it does not get redirected to the main.xhtml page. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper mechanism would be the use of `Filter` .

**See**

- [basic-security-in-jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470591/basic-security-in-jsf)