# Protected URLs leaking unprotected components of the webapge to unauthenticated users

Tags: java, security, jsf, container-managed

I believe implementing security for a JSF application through `<login-config>`+`<security-constraint>`+ `<security-role>` & through use of `<filter>` are two different ways !? Are they ?

I tried implementing security through the first method above(using  `<login-config>`+`<security-constraint>`+ `<security-role>`) but found that my protected webpage that was using both protected & unprotected HTML components was delivered with unprotected resources even to the unauthenticated users.

I need to protect the URLs completely so that the protected URLs don't even leak any part of that webpage to the unauthenticated users. How do I go about that ?

And, is security implementation using `<filter>` in `web.xml` a self managed way to deal with security ? I believe then you can then customize security more fine-grained as you are filtering/catching each & every request ?

Comment: An example of your security-constraint config, and the URLs to authorize would be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It are indeed two distinct ways. The `<security-constraint>` is part of container managed authentication (CMS). The `Filter` is part of homegrown authentication.

To restrict access to certain resources with CMS, you just have to set its `<url-pattern>`:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>someRoleName</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

The above example puts the constraint on all URLs matching `/app/*` and allows access to users with `someRoleName` only.

To restrict access to certain resources with a `Filter`, you have to set its `<url-pattern>` as well:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>authenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>authenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You only have to define roles elsewhere, perhaps as an `<init-param>` of the filter.