# How to restrict access to certain pages with JSF 2 after user has logged in?

Tags: security, jsf-2

I want to restrict access to certain JSF pages based on user access rights. How to do it in JSF ? I have found two links: [Restricting users from accessing pages by directly changing the URL in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090423/restricting-users-from-accessing-pages-by-directly-changing-the-url-in-jsf).
 But  the answer didn't mention how to block access to page. With `response.sendError` ? 
The second link: [JSF: How control access and rights in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516349/jsf-how-control-access-and-rights-in-jsf/)

Also what is the best to use PhaseListener or to use ServletFilter ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *But the answer didn't mention how to block access to page. With response.sendError ?*

It's fully to your choice. It all depends on your business requirements. Do you want to redirect to login page? Just do that!

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
```

Or, do you want to show a scary and user-unfriendly HTTP 401 error? Just do that!

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

At least, *anything* but continuing the request to the restricted resource by `chain.doFilter()`. Otherwise the whole restriction would be pointless.

---

> *Also what is the best to use PhaseListener or to use ServletFilter ?*

A servlet filter is designed to intercept on HTTP requests and runs only once far before `FacesServlet` is invoked and is therefore capable of hooking on non-JSF requests, depending on the URL pattern.

A phase listener is designed to intercept on before- and after-condition of every single JSF phase (there are 6) and runs 2 up to 12 times during a JSF request, depending on the current JSF phase.

What does your common sense say? Which one looks more simple and efficient for the very simple job of allowing/blocking HTTP requests (and thus not JSF phases)? Just use the right tool for the job.

---

For case you're interested, here's a rather complete example of such an authorization filter: [Authorization redirect on session expiration does not work on submitting a JSF form, page stays the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580267/authorization-redirect-on-session-expiration-does-not-work-on-submitting-a-jsf-f/14582031#14582031).

#### See also:

- [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try to use WebFilter-Pattern. If I understand correctly WebFilter will be called on every user request for HTML or AJAX before FacesServlet. My problem is that I don't understand good the Java-API for Web (servlet): /redirect /forward etc. Can I use resp.sendError for redirecting the url to restricted source.

Comment: Use `response.sendRedirect()` to redirect. To learn more about basic filters and servlets, see also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: You provide very nice examples for my question! Thank you!