# Check some specific pages must be login

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, managed-bean

I have created a filter login 
[How to redirect a logged out user to the home page in Java EE/JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148490/how-to-redirect-a-logged-out-user-to-the-home-page-in-java-ee-jsf)

But now I want to set just some specific pages have to login. I created some pages and put them into private folder, and changed the filter's url like this

```
<filter-name>AuthenticationLogin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filter.AuthenticationLogin</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationLogin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It doesn't work :(

Any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your filter mapping is correct. "It doesn't work" is not correct problem description. Can you put breakpoint in `doFilter` method of filter and check what happens when you go to on private page (/private/pagename)? Try use following redirection `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsf");`

Comment: It works perfectly!Thank you! I am a begginer in JSF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter mapping is correct. You can use following redirection

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsf");
```

in filter.