# jsf filter seems not to work

Tags: jsf, authentication, servlet-filters, faces-config

I was trying to create a secure login page with jsf, and I used these code snippets as the solution, found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470591/basic-security-in-jsf). My problem is, that I can access the /restricted/secret.xhtml without logging in, there is no redirect it's like the filter is not applied, because if I go directly to the /restricted/secret.xhtml the #{user.loggedIn} evaluates to false and I still can view the page. Here is my code:

AuthFilter.java

```
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

private FilterConfig config;

@Override
public void destroy() {
    this.config = null;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain ch) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpSession s =  ((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession();
    if (s.getAttribute(UserBean.CREDENTIAL)==null)
    {
        ((HttpServletResponse) resp).sendRedirect("/login.faces");
    }else
    {
        ch.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
}
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.config = config;
}
}
```

UserBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

private String name;
private String password;
protected static final String CREDENTIAL = "ontherun";

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String newName)
{
    this.name = newName;
}

public String getPassword()
{
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String newPassword)
{
    this.password = newPassword;
}

public boolean isLoggedIn()
{
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getSessionMap().get(CREDENTIAL) != null;
}

public String logout() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove(CREDENTIAL);
    return null;
}


public String login()
{
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(CREDENTIAL, this.name);
    return "secret";
}
}
```

Here is my login.xhtml ; the page works correctly, so there is no problem with the template file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head><title>IGNORED</title></head>

<body>
<ui:composition template="/templates/masterLayoutTemplate.xhtml">
 <ui:define name="windowTitle">
             #{msgs.window_title}
 </ui:define>

 <ui:define name="header">
    <ui:include src="/sections/login/header.xhtml"></ui:include>
 </ui:define>

 <ui:define name="footer">
    <ui:include src="/sections/login/footer.xhtml"></ui:include>
 </ui:define>

 <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                #{msgs.namePrompt}
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{user.name}"/>
                #{msgs.passwordPrompt}
            <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p>
            <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.loginButtonText}" action="#{user.login }"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                You are logged in : #{user.loggedIn} 
            </p>
            <p>
            <h:commandButton value="logout" action="#{user.logout }"/>
            </p>
        </h:form>
 </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the secret.xhtml which is supposed to be restricted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head><title>IGNORED</title></head>

<body>
<ui:composition template="/templates/masterLayoutTemplate.xhtml">
 <ui:define name="windowTitle">
     #{msgs.window_title}
 </ui:define>


 <ui:define name="content">
        <h:head></h:head>
        <h:body>
            <p>You are #{user.loggedIn}</p>
        </h:body>


 </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

And here are my config files: web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>OnTheRun</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>on.run.AuthFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

and faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>on.run.messages</base-name>
        <var>msgs</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>



<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/profile.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>secret</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/restricted/secret.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

My directory structure looks like this: [dirStruct](http://i48.tinypic.com/9hjomd.png) [2](http://i48.tinypic.com/9hjomd.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've mapped `FacesServlet` on `/faces/*` instead of `*.xhtml`. So all JSF requests will have the `/faces` prefix in the URL. But you've mapped the `AuthFilter` on `/restricted/*` instead of `/faces/restricted/*`, so it will never kick in on `/faces/*` URLs.

You can solve this in 2 ways:

1. Map `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml` instead of on `/faces/*`. This has the additional advantage that the enduser won't ever be able to see the raw JSF source code when the enduser purposefully removes the `/faces` path from the URL in browser address bar.
2. Map `AuthFilter` on `/faces/restricted/*` instead of on `/restricted/*`.

I personally recommend the first way. You end up with a shorter and nicer URL and you immediately also prevent the JSF source code leak.

Comment: Thank you, for your help. I also had to modify in the filter the redirection path to "../login.xhtml". Is there a more elegant way to do this> I mean how can I set my path to load the projects directory? In my case if I just write login.xhtml or /login.xhtml it redirects to localhost/login.xhtml, not localhost/ProjectName/login.xhtml.

Comment: Use `String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml";`.