# Using LDAP/JAAS Authentication in WebSphare Application Server

Tags: java, ldap, websphere, jaas

I have a JSF Web Application that will be deployed on WAS 8.5.

I defined LDAP configurations on WAS level.

I want to know how to use container authentication in my application login screen.

Is there any sample code to use ?

Thanks

Comment: And your problem is? Have you tried anything? Did you created form with j_security_check action? Or you just want someone else to do all the searching for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form Login (JEE Web Application security)
  for your web application. You will have to 
1) Enable application Security in WebSphere Application Server.
2) Update the web.xml for your web application to use Form login

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/mylogin.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/FormLoginErrPage.jsp</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

3) Create the mylogin.html/jsp and FormLoginErrPage.jsp

You might also want to look at another questions [Basic Security in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470591/basic-security-in-jsf)